# Date Simulation : Move date to business day without conflicted date SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have problem in creating query for date simulation.

```
dkd_kd      mr      LAST_EVENT_PROC DayOfLAST_EVENT_PROC    BusinessDay
------------------------------------------------------------------------
C01R0307    bma16   5               Monday                  5
C01R0304    bma16   4               Sunday                  5
C01R0305    bma12   4               Sunday                  5
C01R0313    bma12   3               Saturday                3
```

I have created a function to skip Sunday as business day, but I need the `BusinessDay` exist in `LAST_EVENT_PROC` and have same 'mr' then BusinessDay + 1

This is my query :

```
SELECT
    dkd_kd,
    mr,
    next_tgl_baca,
    datepart(day,LAST_EVENT_PROC) as LAST_EVENT_PROC,
    DATENAME(weekday, LAST_EVENT_PROC) AS DayOfLAST_EVENT_PROC,
    DATEPART(day, DATEADD(dd, CASE 
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, 0, LAST_EVENT_PROC) % 7 > 5 
                                  THEN 7 - DATEDIFF(dd, 0, LAST_EVENT_PROC) % 7
                                WHEN DATENAME(weekday, LAST_EVENT_PROC) = 'Monday' 
                                  THEN 7 - DATEDIFF(dd, 1, LAST_EVENT_PROC) % 7
                                ELSE 0 END, LAST_EVENT_PROC)) AS NextBusinessDay
FROM
    tm_perkiraan_konsumsi
JOIN 
    tr_kode_rute ON tm_perkiraan_konsumsi.dkd_kd = tr_kode_rute.rute
WHERE 
    next_tgl_baca <> '' AND pk_id LIKE '%6:02PM%';
```